# Applying value to buffer area using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, buffer

The aim of the investigation is to determine the range of pollution concentrations which the paths (purple) are exposed to from roads (the yellow bands represent concentrations at different distances)(Figure 1)[image].
I am trying to give the bands the concentration value so that I can perform an intersect and obtain the values which the paths are exposed to.

How can I apply value to the buffer area?

I know I can convert to raster, I have tried this but the end result is rather sketchy (Figure 2)[image].

Answer (score 3):

A rather simple approach would be to add a field to the layers attribute table and paste the correct value there manually. This may result in a lot of work, depending on how many features there are in your layers.

If you obtained a distinct layer for each distance, you may also add the field to tbe attribute table and the use ArcGIS' equivalent to the field calculator, saying something like

```
"fieldname" = value
```

Sorry for being rather vague, but I hope you get the idea.

Word of warning: To be scientifically sound, you should not use fixed distance buffers for pollution estimation, but rather a full model, incorporating things like buildings, airflow, etc.

Comment: Thank you, I have joined the values to the buffers through a join (i.e. I have the values in Excel spreadsheets which I have Joined to the Buffers.